# Avoiding Activity Leak with Dagger 2 Scope

Tags: android, android-activity, dependency-injection, dagger-2

If I have an Navigator like so:

```
class Navigator(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
   fun somemethods() {
       activity.supportFragmentTransaction.beginTransaction()...
   }
}
```

and I provide the Activity to the Navigator by DI (Dagger 2) with a scope:

```
@Module
class NavigatorModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun getNavigator(activity: SomeActivity) {
        return Navigator(activity)
    }

}
```

then in my activity:

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity().... {
    @Inject
    lateinit var navigator: Navigator

    ....
}
```

Will this avoid leaking the activity? I assume that the Navigator Object will be Garbage Collected together with the Activity when the activity is recreated. Am I right or wrong about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the setup you show should be fine. Anything within your ActivityComponent can safely reference the Activity and it will all be garbage collected at some point once it gets destroyed.

The only thing that you have to watch out for is that you don't reference any of those objects from longer-lived ones, e.g. subscribe to listen for changes on a Singleton object.

---

I suggest you add [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to your project which will pop up a notification whenever you forget to unregister some listener.